# CrafterCMS has no site configured after initial setup

Tags: crafter-cms

I downloaded the tar.gz for authoring with profile and social and also without profile and social.

With startup.sh http://localhost:8080/studio shows `no site configured. Please configure the site you want to show or select a site on the authoring environment.`

A quick look of the deployer logs show `No config files found under /crafter/data/deployer/targets`. No good documentation is available on this. I tried creating a yaml file after reading https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.0/system-administrators/deployer/admin-guide.html still it doesn't change the situation.

I haven't tinkered with any configurations I only followed the quick start guide. No login page is also being displayed.

I am using version 3.1.10 and I have 8 gb of ram.

The tomcat log file has quite a lot of characters. I have attached it in gdrive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-t37ETNWG94qcMnrXdIfwkHRa1khhtKp/view?usp=sharing

I have also attached the deployer logs
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A1hNvIdQeMPOVTfTDv_PtU2Xa10r-mwK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: - What version of Crafter CMS did you download? (you seem to be referring to 3.0 in the docs).
- Attach your start up logs, it seems that Studio didn't start. Logs are in logs/tomcat/catalina.out
- How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Hi sumerz, I have updated the question

Comment: I think you are right with the ram size. I have 8 gigs total and I dont think JVM can take all 8 up. I will try to set it up on our server with 32 gigs and see what happens

Comment: Consider using the free AMIs from AWS to try things out, they're here: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=6d75ffca-9630-44bd-90b4-ac0e99058995

Also, https://gist.github.com is a good way to share logs (easier)

Comment: @sumerz How can I modify jvm space for crafter? I have the same issue on a 32gb machine. I also get an "unexpected operator" on startup.sh https://gist.github.com/akudekar/36dd98fbd27665c6d1de25d392360e17

Answer (score 0):

From your logs, it seems that you're missing ncurses5:

```
[ERROR] 2020-11-25T12:05:36,874 [Exec Stream Pumper] [exec.ManagedProcess] | mysql_secure_installation: /home/aditya/Desktop/crafter/bin/dbms/bin/mysql: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

That breaks the authoring database. To fix this, see the instructions for your Linux distro here:

https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/system-administrators/activities/installing-and-verifying-prerequisites.html#linux-prerequisite

Comment: Hi @sumerz. This worked thank you. Sorry I didn't notice the prerequisite error